# Dynamically change icon of a widget in NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-platform

I am currently developing a plugin for NetBeans (in short the goal is to integrate my company's tool to NetBeans), and I thought it would be good to have a little widget on the widget bar to tell if my tool is enabled or not.

I saw [Geertjan blog post](https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/add-widget-via-action-in-toolbar-part-1)  regarding widget buttons, but what he does is enable/disable the button, what I want to do is to change the icon to notify the user of the tools status, and when he clicks on it turns on/off the tool.

Is it doable on NetBeans?

I tried to change `layer.xml` `iconbase` attribute to a method to dynamically change this but it doesn't seem to work, at least with when I tried (`<attr name="iconBase" stringvalue="TWIconWidget.CTCIcon.getIconPath"/>`)

I also tried with an `ImageWidget` cast on the `actionPerformed()` of a widget but I can't find a way to see it in the widget toolbar.

Do you have any tips on how to do this?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT :**
If it is not possible, can you offer some alternatives to it, such as a [slide button](http://www.jqueryscript.net/images/jQuery-Plugin-For-Tri-state-Toggle-Switch-Candlestick.jpg) or something that could suit the needs and be visible on the widget bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This post shows a way to do it (credits to the author Hermien Pellissier): http://www.pellissier.co.za/hermien/?p=646

Basically you create an `Action` using the Netbeans wizard and modify it to extend from `AbstractAction` and implement `Presenter.Toolbar`.

You can then override `getToolbarPresenter()` to return any `Component` you want to show in the toolbar, for example a `JButton` or a custom component.

Using the `Component` methods you can change its appearance, for example:

```
public final class SomeAction extends AbstractAction implements Presenter.Toolbar {

    private JButton button;

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // change the button image
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("another_image.png");
        button.setIcon(icon);
    }

    @Override
    public Component getToolbarPresenter() {
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("image.png");

        // create the button to show
        button = new JButton(icon);
        button.addActionListener(this);

        return button;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice one, tried it and it works, thank you verry much!